# Using vlmc to calculate the log likelihood of a second dataset

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the R package VLMC to build a bayesian classifier. 
By executing:

```
foo = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b", "c")
bar = vlmc(foo)
print(logLik(foo))
```

I am able train a model `bar` on a dataset `foo` and get the log-likelihood of the data `foo` under the model `bar`.  If I have another dataset, say `foobar`,
how can I use the vlmc package to get the log likelihood of `foobar` under the model `bar` trained on the data `foo`?

Comment: The package doesn't have an option to give you a log-likelihood for another data set. At best you can get a probability matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the VMM package (not in CRAN) is actually better suited to this task.